# Does com.apple.security.device.serial let me access the keyboard?

Tags: objective-c, macos, entitlements

I have an app that uses the microphone, keyboard, and camera. It works well in Xcode, but in the app store it is apparently sandboxed and so it can't access the keyboard anymore.

I added
com.apple.security.device.serial
to my Entitlements, but just want to make sure that this does grant access to the keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried it? What happens when you run it on your machine?

Comment: Hi, I changed the question a bit since you responded, but yes, it works perfectly when ran from Xcode, but when ran from the mac app store version it cannot access they keyboard.

Comment: The App Store won't (in fact, can't) sandbox an app that you upload that you didn't sandbox. (They'll just reject your app if it's not sandboxed.). Are you running a different build? If you go into the Organizer and create a local installer and install that, does it still work? What if you give yourself a free coupon and download it from the App Store on your machine? Are you actually getting sandbox log messages, or something different? What makes you sure it's not, e.g., 10.9 vs. 10.8?